# Убрать отступы из url - php

Tags: php

Есть переменная в которой хранится id паблика Вконтакте.Перед этим она была взята с текстового файла.И есть строка такого типа

> http://vk.com/**здесь будет ид**?act=member

Проблема в том на выходе строка получается с отступом:

> http://m.vk.com/pub11232123 ?act=members

Пытался убрать str_replace - вообще никак.
Склеивал и расклеивал строку - никак:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если отступы пробельные/перевода строки, то функция [`trim()`](http://www.php.su/trim). Примените её к переменной, содержащей id, перед непосредственной вставкой в url.